# time of 'fire'ing' (not creating) proces in winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, process

I need to obtain an exact time of fire'ing process
(not the time of the creation of the proces which 
as I know is some time later) I need to obtain 
the time of 'running' program yet before its image
is loaded into memory. Is it obtainable?

Side question - all running processes in winapi 
are created thru CreateProcess/Ex function 
calls (Then the time I need would be the
time of calling such function) or ther are
some other ways of running processes in windows
under the hood?

Comment: You want the time at which `CreateProcess` was called? Or how long it takes? The answer to the first question is use `GetProcessTimes` and the answer to the second is "why do you care and it can take any amount of time."

Comment: I need time of fire'ing process - this means probabli the time of CreateProces/Ex call (but not sure if all called processes go through that) Donts say that GetProcesTimes gives that if it doeas some later time, also do not tel me that i should not care - its terribly stupid

Comment: `GetProcessTimes` will give you the only *reasonable* answer: the time that Windows recorded as the process creation time; where, exactly, in the process creation codepath Windows considers a process "created" is irrelevant (also possibly different between versions of Windows). So if the answer that `GetProcessTimes` returns doesn't fit your needs, that's too bad.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick. It returns the process creation time, which corresponds to when the kernel object was actually created irrespective of when/if the image's code is executed.

Comment: No AFAIK it is the time of creation and I am searching for tame when one just commands system to BEGIN to run some file - I am searching for this most early time - not some later times - I need this begining time to exact measuring of time of setupping process - from run command to its first contained code executions :/

Comment: Your question is really *meaningless* (Windows doesn't just "run some file" - there's a lot of stuff that happens in the background) and the creation time given to `GetProcessTimes` is about as close to a sensible answer as you're possible going to get.

Comment: Not so close I thing this is probably after loading exe image mapping dlls and so (it all can take probably a lot o miliseconds - so you answer is terribly wrong and strangely stupid) I need the time of fire'ing process

Comment: Loading the EXE image and mapping DLLs is *how* Windows "fires" the process. Nothing "stupid" about this answer.

Comment: Stupid is telling me I want time after loading and mapping when I need the time before - isn't it stupid ? it is - I do not want the time after loading image (are you blind, cant you read) so do not answer me that

Comment: You are hopelessly confused and unbelievably rude. This is simply not how Windows works. A process does not run until all of those things happen. There is simply no answer to your question. I can't even imagine what you *think* you're wanting. The time that the user completed the second click on the icon?

Comment: Yes, this sort of things - or console command ended with [enter] - it is probably the time of CreateProsess/Ex call (see second part of the question) I need exactly THAT no other things, and I also need at least 1 milisecond resolution not less :c

Comment: I am not totaly sure if it is CreateProcessEx call moment becouse of two things 1) I am not absolutely sure if every process run goes thru that (but) probably 2) I am not sure if between CreateProcessEx and moment of starting when loader starts to load image then mapss dll, there is never any delay - I am interested in this moment when process loader starts - that exact moment

Comment: As I said before, `GetProcessTimes` will give you the only *reasonable* answer to your inquiry - although it's unlikely to be the "exact moment" but some moment through the process creation code path. If that information doesn't fit your needs (and I don't see why it *possibly* would not), well that's just too bad.

Comment: It's simply not going to happen. Your assumption that "CreateProcess" is called at the instant the user double-clicks the mouse is probably wrong, and even if it *is* correct, Windows does not make any guarantees about that. You aren't entitled to that information, its an internal implementation detail. Makes sense, because this information is useless to you. Whatever reason you think you need it, there's sure to a better way to solve that problem. Besides, this pursuit of "at least 1 millisecond resolution not less" is folly—Windows is not a real-time OS. You can't have that guarantee.

Comment: Is it real time or not - it is some moment in time - CreatteProcess is probably much l8er, I want the FIRST moment (timestamp) involved in the proces of running program, it is related to CreateProcesEx I think, also the time of begining loading exe image is somewhat related to that but I think it may be also l8er time and I want the first (It is needed 4 presise measurement of program startup time, from the command to run it till the moment where first linec in the main procedure are began to execute

Comment: @grungefightr Again, you are making *many* assumptions that simply don't apply. A ton of stuff happens before the first line in `main` is invoked and the first time a program is launched, more of that stuff will happen than in subsequent times. Also, Windows might interrupt the loading process to do other work (service interrupts, switch to different applications, etc) so the "wall clock" time you get is meaningless. And I could go on. You use the words "I think" a lot. Perhaps you should stop doing that and listen to what people who *know* are telling you. Also: "l8er"? **Really**?